# Received message differs from sent message over serial connection

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial, uart

I am trying to connect two raspberries over a serial connection with pyserial. I wrote two little scripts, for transmitting and receiving. While there is a communication happening between those two, the received message is completely different, than the sent message.

For example if I do

```py
serial1.write(b'hello')
```

on raspi1, then raspi2 receives:

```py
print(serial2.readline().hex())
fa9b9fff
```

which is the hex representation of `ú›Ÿÿ`.

EDIT: Here is the receive and send methods:

sender:

```py
def send_msg(_ser, _msg):
    if _ser.isOpen():  # isOpen() is deprecated since version 3.0
        try:
            _ser.flushInput()  # flush input buffer, discarding all its contents
            _ser.flushOutput()  # flush output buffer, aborting current output 
            # and discard all that is in buffer

            _ser.write(_msg)
            _ser.flush()

        except IOError:
            print('error communicating...')

    else:
        print('cannot open serial port')
    return
```

receiver:

```py
def read_line(_ser, _eol_character=b'\n', _timeout=1, _encoding='utf-8'):
    buffer = ""
    timer = time.time()
    while (time.time()-timer)<_timeout:
        one_byte = _ser.read(1)
        print(one_byte.hex())
        if one_byte == _eol_character:
            return buffer.encode(_encoding)
        else:
            buffer += str(one_byte, _encoding, errors='replace')
    raise TimeoutError("Timed out while read_line(), make sure there is an EOF!")
```

Comment: It's not easy to say if you show just one line of code. What you see usually comes from a mismatch of settings, in particular different baud rates or a hardware issue. Are you GND signals connected?

Comment: @MarcosG. I have two different usb-rs232 devices, one which only has Tx and Rx. May the different voltages of the devices be the issue?

Comment: That might be an issue, yes.

Comment: Just to be clear one of your devices is full RS232 compliant with a SUB-D9 connector and the other is a TTL 3.3 or 5V?

Comment: yes, I just saw that there is an unused GND junction on the TTL PCB. I will try connecting both GND after soldered a cable to the unused GND

Comment: OK but you better first make sure your cable supports TTL levels.

Comment: Thank you @MarcosG.! Connecting the GND resolved my problem! Would you mind to write a short summary as an answer (so i can mark it as an answer) for other people trying to solve this problem?

Comment: done, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kind of gibberish you're getting indicates three possible causes:

-A mismatch of settings, most likely different baud rates

-Noise on the bus: frequently originating from lacking a common ground reference. This happens when you have not connected only connect the TX and RX signals but leave the GND floating (on desktop computers you'll likely have a common ground even if you don't connect the GND signals because of the safety ground on your house's wiring but on laptops or other battery-powered devices this is a problem and you have to use a third cable to connect GND on both sides of the bus).

-You're trying to communicate using different logic levels. This happens if one side of the bus is working on TTL levels (5V) and the other on 3.3V or when you have a real RS232 level (differential) combined with any of the others. Not to mention if you try to mix RS485 with RS232 or TTL, which, of course, won't work either.